# How do you edit or select background events in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar's [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) to implement blocked dates and days in my application.

But I cannot find any option to edit or select the background event from the calendar. For example how can i drag or resize background events?
Also it appears clicked events doesn't register on background events so i'm not able to select and delete them.

I have tried setting the [editable field](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) on the background event to true but it appears it doesn't have any effect.

```
events: [
  {
    start: '2019-04-11T10:00:00',
    end: '2019-04-11T16:00:00',
    rendering: 'background',
    color: '#ff9f89',
    editable : true
  },
  {
    start: '2019-04-13T10:00:00',
    end: '2019-04-13T16:00:00',
    rendering: 'background',
    color: '#ff9f89',
    editable: true
  }
]
```

I was expecting that I could use the editable property to allow editing the background event but it doesn't the event is still not editable.

Comment: The whole point of background events is that they're just there for illustrative purposes. They're _in the background_, staying out of the way, not to be interacted with. So no, there is no way to manipulate them once they're placed on the calendar (aside from adding your own JS code to explicitly update or delete the event objects, of course)

Comment: I would agree though, that the documentation does not appear to mention this fact, which is a bit of an omission really.

Comment: I think it is unfortunate that the "editable" property is ignored. I would understand if the default is set to false, but if it explicitly is set to true I expect this to be handled differently. Currently I am implementing a view where caregivers set their availability (background events) and in which they can see scheduled appointments (not editable from here).